# how to delete images with a specific number with a bash script?

Tags: windows, bash, find

My goal is to write a script that will belete all .jpg named with a "_0".

Example: foo_0.jpg and bar_0.jpg.

expected behaviour of the script: Delete all files with "_0.jpg"
I attempt to:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name _0.jpg -type f -delete
```

results in unexpected error massage:
`FIND: Parameter format not correct`

If using `find "_0.jpg" . -name -type f -delete`  in folder direct from the command line I get the unexpected result:

```
Access denied - .
File not found - -NAME
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - -DELETE
```

Update:
running `find ""*_0.jpg""` does find the files.

expected behaviour deletes foo_0.jpg and bar_0.jpg.
run `find ""*_0.jpg"" -name f -delete` or running `find ""*_0.jpg"" -exec rm "{}"`
unexpected result running bash -x (debug):

```
 + find foo_0.jpg bar_0.jpg . -name f -delete
FIND: Parameter format not correct
+ find '*_0' -exec rm '{find *_0}'
File not found - *_0
+ exit 0
```

Update 2:
Due to a Windows issue (using wrong `find`) I installed findutils `choco install -y findutils` Added a new PATH and moved `system32` down.
Result run: `find --help`

```
default path is the current directory; default expression is -print
expression may consist of: operators, options, tests, and actions:

operators (decreasing precedence; -and is implicit where no others are given):
      ( EXPR )   ! EXPR   -not EXPR   EXPR1 -a EXPR2   EXPR1 -and EXPR2
      EXPR1 -o EXPR2   EXPR1 -or EXPR2   EXPR1 , EXPR2

positional options (always true): -daystart -follow -regextype

normal options (always true, specified before other expressions):
      -depth --help -maxdepth LEVELS -mindepth LEVELS -mount -noleaf
      --version -xdev -ignore_readdir_race -noignore_readdir_race

tests (N can be +N or -N or N): -amin N -anewer FILE -atime N -cmin N
      -cnewer FILE -ctime N -empty -false -fstype TYPE -gid N -group NAME
      -ilname PATTERN -iname PATTERN -inum N -iwholename PATTERN -iregex PATTERN
      -links N -lname PATTERN -mmin N -mtime N -name PATTERN -newer FILE
      -nouser -nogroup -path PATTERN -perm [+-]MODE -regex PATTERN
      -wholename PATTERN -size N[bcwkMG] -true -type [bcdpflsD] -uid N
      -used N -user NAME -xtype [bcdpfls]

actions: -delete -print0 -printf FORMAT -fprintf FILE FORMAT -print
      -fprint0 FILE -fprint FILE -ls -fls FILE -prune -quit
      -exec COMMAND ; -exec COMMAND {} + -ok COMMAND ;
      -execdir COMMAND ; -execdir COMMAND {} + -okdir COMMAND ;

Report (and track progress on fixing) bugs via the findutils bug-reporting
page at http://savannah.gnu.org/ or, if you have no web access, by sending
email to <bug-findutils@gnu.org>.
```

using:

- OS: Windows 10 pro
- Cmder

Comment: Do you mean `'*0.jpg'`? Should `a10.jpg` be deleted, too?

Comment: -name "*_0.jpg"?

Comment: @choroba I mean all `_0.jpg` files. An `a10.jpg` may not be deleted

Comment: @RamanSailopal if using `-name "*_0.jpg"`   result is : `+ find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -delete
FIND: Parameter format not correct`. Note that the 0 is gone.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Joehoe : In the attempt you posted, you are searching for files named exactly `0.jpg` to be deleted; but the command you wrote in the question would not produce the error message you received, so what you posted here is clearly different from what you actually executed.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but all your error messages look like nasty Windows error messages, so I wonder if your PATH means you are actually using some Microsoft tool called `FIND.EXE` instead of the lovely Linux `find`... I guess you'd need to run `type find` or `which find` or `echo $PATH` to find out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi, did add path to my variables. Still strugling with the syntacs. While find.exe finds all files now due to the `"" ""` deleting them still doesn't work

Comment: What happens if you run the find command in a normal Windows bash shell?

Comment: @RamanSailopal running in PowerShell doesn't make a difference

Comment: Did you try `find /?` in case you are using Windows `FIND.EXE`

Comment: @MarkSetchell no didn't try `find /?` this gives me a helpfull output wich i tried with `-h` and `--help` But doesn't mention how to delete files `find` found.

Comment: If it looks anything like this https://ss64.com/nt/find.html you are running the nasty Windows `FIND.EXE` not the lovely Linux one.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it looks exactly like a nasty Windows `FIND.EXE`. Does that make this a mission impossible?

Comment: No, it means your PATH has something like `C:\Windows\System32` too soon, before the directory containing the lovely GNU/Linux `find`. I don't know where the Linux one is because I don't run Windows, so hopefully someone else can help. Maybe edit your question to show that the PATH is the issue so it is obvious what needs doing to regular Windows users. Sorry I don't know more. Good luck!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Installed the right `find` and modified PATH `c/../../chocolatey/bin/find`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added a second update. Does this looks more like the lovely GNU/linux `find` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Installing an other find was extually the answer for my question. Would you please create an answer? `find . -name '*_0.jpg' -type f -delete -print0` works like a charm now. With expected result: `+ find . -name '*_0.jpg' -type f -delete -print0
./00333_0.jpg ./00345_0.jpg + exit 0`

Comment: Glad we've got you running - good luck with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Microsoft `FIND.EXE` rather than the lovely GNU/Linux `find` utility. The giveaways are the capitalisation of the error message and its unhelpful nature - *"Parameter Incorrect"*.

You can confirm this by running this:

```
FIND /?
```

and if the output looks anything like [this](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html), it is the Windows `FIND.EXE`.

The solution is to install a version of the GNU `find` which you have located yourself as part of `findutils` from **Chocolatey Software**.

Comment: You can see `Chocolatey` or `choco` more as a package manager like pacman is for manjaro. It's a lazy way of installing/upgrade software. `findutils` isn't a part of `Chocolatey`. But the most easy, read lazy, way to install packages/software like `find`.